# Is mysqlcheck output buffered

Tags: mariadb

I have 15 databases running MariaDB with roughly 1000 tables each. Nightly I run mysqlcheck to repair and optimize the tables which takes around an hour. I've tail -F'd the log before and it looks like it runs through around 900 tables at once, outputs it's finding, then does a bunch more. I decided to run the output through a timestamper (ts from moreutils) so I can verify this and see which tables take the longest and potentially clean up unnecessary data. The output from the command shows the first table takes 13 minutes, then it does 900 tables at 0 seconds each, then it stops for 13 minutes on another table. None of the tables it stops on are particularly big nor slammed. 
So my question is, is mysqlcheck buffering it's output and is there a way to prevent it from doing so, or am I looking at writing a manual script?

Command: `/usr/bin/mysqlcheck -p<PASSWORD> -A --auto-repair -o`

Server version: 10.0.29-MariaDB SLE 12 SP1

Answer (score 0):

(This "Answer" does not *answer* the Question; it *eliminates* the Question.)

Don't use MyISAM; switch to InnoDB.  That gets rid of the need to repair tables.

Don't use MyISAM; switch to InnoDB.  That gets rid of the need to `OPTIMIZE` tables.

Comment: The way the software was written, InnoDB is NOT compatible. We have to stay with MyISAM.

Comment: Consider breaking up the long list of tables into shorter lists.  Or check with "quick" and optimize only if Data_free is more than 10% of Data_length.